# Entity Framework - Use join table to return collections of Followers / Following

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using Entity Framework, I am writing a social networking app and trying to setup some relationships so that I can have Users with Followers/Following properties.

I have a Users table:

```
Users
_______
Id
FirstName
LastName
Email
```

Then I have a Follows table:

```
Follows
__________
FollowerId
FolloweeId
```

On a strongly typed User object, I want to see .Followers and .Following properties that return collections of User objects. So far I've tried making the columns in the Follows table as foreign keys, and both as composite primary keys. The entity model comes out the way I want it (I don't have an Entity in-between, and I just have to rename the navigation properties), but when I populate with data, the Followers and Following collections are empty, so something is not right with the relationships.

I suppose I could separate and have two tables, Followers and Following, but I would have duplicate data and would have to add to two tables when someone follows someone else.

Comment: Just check the associations between the enitites, and make sure you are saving the db. Can your EF save anything (other than followers/followees), check that one. If yes, check if followers/folowees are whether being written successfully to the db or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the data for the tables you User tables has relationships with in your query.

A query like this:

```
using (EntityObject context = new EntityObject())
{
    var user = from x in context.users.Include("Followers").Include("Followees") //use your tables
               where x.Id == TheUserId
               select x;


}
```

Will let you have access to the objects for those included tables.